# automate deploy datafactory ARM template

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I am trying to automate the deploiement of azure datafactory arm template 
I am following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements

```
 Failed to export ARM template. Error:  No resource found in specified input path: C:\\azp\\agent\\_work\\26/self/ADF. Please set correct path and try again.
```

Is there some prequistes files to put in the root folder before running the command?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you are trying to run:

```
npm run build export C:\DataFactories\DevDataFactory /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/testResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/DevDataFactory ArmTemplateOutput
```

In this case, your ADF folder has to contain ADF sources. Do you use source control for it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control

You may disable publishing from the adf_publish branch if your trying to use deployment from sources: [Editing repo settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#editing-repo-settings)